# How do I restrict the sample domain when using the sample() function of a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, random

Here is my code:

```
set = read.table(filename, header = T, sep = ",")
halfset <- dataset[sample(nrows, nrows/2), ]
```

Based on this, halfset is supposed to be a randomly selected set of points from set. However, halfset has a problematic data point (the first one) that I want to make sure is not included in halfset.

How do I make sure that this one point is not included in the sample? I can't modify the original set.

Comment: Sample from the dataset minus the first row?

Comment: `dataset[sample( 2:nrowdataset), nrow(dataset)/2), ]`